# UITableCell Autoresizing with Autolayout doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I'm programming in Xamarin iOS. Basically the table cell doesn't resize and instead just always stays in a static size (even after typing text and new lines).

I have a xib which contains a UITextView and 4 constrains as needed plus the height constraint(removing the height constraint will make it appear in zero size)

In the ViewDidLoad() method I'm using the following:

```
TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 50;
TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
```

In ViewWillAppear() I'm also using the same lines.

I also tried using this

```
    public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 80;//autodimension also didn't work here.
    }
```

and finally `GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)`

None of them worked.

[XIB and application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0DBJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample code in Objective-C demonstrates the idea.

The rewritten code in C#

```
editTextView.Changed += (s, e) => {
                // Sizing: 
                var size = editTextView.SizeThatFits(new CoreGraphics.CGSize(Frame.Width, nfloat.MaxValue));
                var height = size.Height;
                if (height < 50)
                {
                    this.EditTextHeight.Constant = 50;
                    //self.heightConstraint.constant = 50;
                }
                else {
                    this.EditTextHeight.Constant = height;
                    //self.heightConstraint.constant = height;
                }
                // call the tableview-updates in the controller
                NotifyOnTextChanged.Invoke();
            };
```

Comment: Replaced it, and still the textview is behind the table cell.

Comment: send your xib screen shot

Comment: if your text content is pre filled ?

Comment: see the image and uncheck scrolling enabled

Comment: fixed that issue ?

Comment: Nope it didn't help

Comment: I can't it's an inner company code, I can only tell you snippets of code.

Comment: I've updated the code, you can see the new image I've uploaded, tell me what you think

Comment: I believe it is a step forward, only one last thing is holding us from the final answer, if I edit your textview (add/remove lines) the textview doesn't resize!!! <- if you can make it work, I believe the concept will be the same!!

Comment: I don't see any updates yet, maybe you didn't commit ?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, haha now my only task is to basically "translate" the objective-c to C# (or swift)
Do you know how to write this line in swift or C# ?
 CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGFLOAT_MAX)];

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I've managed to retype it and it works!
Although the size is not fixed, I'll try to see what's wrong there ;)

Answer (score 2):

to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension work you have to set all left, right, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And final

So, for make this working every UIViews in cell we need to set constrains like this according to contenview of cell

[image]

Comment: Indeed, that's something I tried and yet it still doesn't work. I currently see my cell, I click on it and type inside(it does type because I can see autocorrection) but I don't see the text, neither the cell grows. @SMi

Comment: first clear all constrains from you cell. Do you have only one textview in cell? then select the textview and drag it like i do in image four side

Comment: Yes I only have a textview in my content view, what happens is as shown in the images I've uploaded in the post, meaning I see the cell but the text is hidden under the cell. @SMi

Comment: See the last image please. Is something like this in your cell?

Comment: No, because I'm using a xib, there is no tableview cell neither storyboard, just an external cell.

Comment: same as in table view.set the constrains from the nib.drag the four constrains from textview to the cell content view

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did and still no reaction. I've replaced the last image with the constrains(yes I tried the equal for all too)

Comment: See the textview . Is it's height is increasing when you typing or long text? can it hold 2/3 lines of text?

Comment: I can't see it, it's basically behind the cell

Comment: Type in your .xib . see their and see the textview setup there

Comment: I can see the text in the xib, but when running the program it doesn't show it

Comment: Look at the new image I've put in the Question post.

Comment: Put the text view under a UIStackView. set contrains

Comment: yeah, it's a big project and it makes the Xamarin studio crazy for some reason